# Upgrade to Mesa 13 or 17

Tags: 16.04, ppa, mesa

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16.04.2 with Mesa 12,
is it safe to upgrade to newer Mesa with ppa for better performance?
which ppa repo. Is it suitable?
My GPU model=AMD 7400m

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. You also probably need to update your kernel. Are you already using hwe kernels? Check with uname -a and if you're still on 4.4 upgrade your kernel by activating [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack). This is [how-to](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_-_Xenial_Xerus).

I advice to use the `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates` to have the last stable mesa.